# Failed to generate Keystone DB

Tags: openstack

i've tried to install Openstack Havana on My ubuntu 12.04.
But trouble come when i tried to generate keystone database with "keystone-manage db_sync"

Bellow error meessage appear when i try to generated my keystone db

```
$ keystone-manage db_sync
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/keystone-manage", line 4, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import require; require('keystone==2013.2.a104.g3ed9c32')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2711, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: SQLAlchemy>=0.7.8,<=0.7.9
```

Based on that log, it said that SQLAlchemy is not found, but i have installed it using

```
apt-get install python3-sqlalchemy*
```

But keystone still not working now

Any clue how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the error log it seems keystone in openstack havana uses python 2.7. To install sqlalchemy for python 2.7, do the following on a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sqlalchemy
```

Comment: Yah, i change my sqlalchemy version to be 0.7.9 version


    $ sudo pip install -U sqlalchemy==0.7.9


Now keystone working well :)